# Validar datas com Jquery validate para dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-validate

Quero validar as datas com JQuery Validate, porém erro,
Pesquisei bastante mais as soluções encontradas não resolveu meu problema.

meu JS:

```
// incluir todos elementos do form na pagina
$("form").each(function () {
    // inicializa o plugin no each form
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            dataentrada: {
                dateBR: true
            },
            datavenc: {
                dateBR: true
            },
            dataproc: {
                dateBR: true

            }
        }
    });
}
);

//Valida Data PT-BR
jQuery.validator.addMethod("dateBR", function (value, element) {
    //contando chars
    if (value.length != 10)
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    // verificando data
    var data = value;
    var dia = data.substr(0, 2);
    var barra1 = data.substr(2, 1);
    var mes = data.substr(3, 2);
    var barra2 = data.substr(5, 1);
    var ano = data.substr(6, 4);
    if (data.length != 10 || barra1 != "/" || barra2 != "/" || isNaN(dia) || isNaN(mes) || isNaN(ano) || dia > 31 || mes > 12) {
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    }
    if ((mes == 4 || mes == 6 || mes == 9 || mes == 11) && dia == 31) {
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    }
    if (mes == 2 && (dia > 29 || (dia == 29 && ano % 4 !== 0))) {
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    }
    if (ano < 1900) {
        return this.optional(element) || false;
    }
    return this.optional(element) || true;
}, "Informe uma data válida"); /* Mensagem padrão */
```

Quando no navegador tiro o foco do campo, mostra mensagem de data invalida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

1. Crie um arquivo com o nome  methods_pt.js com o conteúdo abaixo.
2. Adicione o arquivo no local onde você faz a chamada o jquery (após)

Veja outra forma de fazer em: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/4076

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
    date: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d\d?\/\d\d?\/\d\d\d?\d?$/.test(value);
    },
    number: function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)?$/.test(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: removi a função acima e coloquei esse dado.
não deu certo, continua exibindo a mensagem mesma com a data correta.
Veja a sequencia do meu js no head da pagina: 
  http://imgur.com/giNUPLll.png

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tjd5s0ba/3/
coloquei um exemplo aqui, não funciona.

Comment: Analisando o seu perfil, vi que você utiliza C#. Nesse caso seria melhor você utilizar o jquery validate unobtrusive. Utilizo para realizar esse tipo de validação, uma vez que você pode decorar uma ViewModel com data anotations e automatizar esse processo.

Comment: mais nesse caso, estou utilizando PHP.

Comment: Entendi, pelo que li tbm é possível utilizá-lo em outras linguagens tbm.